# Mailchimp Popup embed in Shopify "Uncaught ReferenceError: ouibounce is not defined"

Tags: jquery, shopify

On this Shopify website, I have embedded Mailchimp's popup signup form script:
http://www.majisports.com/

And here is the script:
require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us2.list-manage.com","uuid":"c24619bb3e83c43c0dd5d61a1","lid":"b01037f410"}) })

But on the website, I'm getting this error:
"Uncaught ReferenceError: ouibounce is not defined"

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I had a popup app plus my own manual popup code from Mailchimp and they were conflicting with each other. I removed the app and the Mailchimp code works now!